# Android Studio - El botón "Run app" no me funciona

Tags: android, android-studio, depuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imágen, mi celular está conectado **(usb)** pero el botón *"Correr app."* no se activa.

Tengo las opciones de desarrollador activadas y depuración por USB activado también.

**Información extra:**

Hacía 2 meses no utilizaba el IDE android studio. Hoy, al volver, me encontré con este problema que seguramente venga por alguna nueva update que haya habido

**¿Alguna solución?**

Comment: Revisar la ventana  de la terminal puede mostrarse un error especifico.

Answer (score 1):

**El hecho de tener conectado tu dispositivo en Android Studio es independiente a que el botón "Run 'app'" se encuentre habilitado.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el botón "Run 'app'" no se habilita es debido a que tu proyecto no puede ser construido correctamente.

Causas:

- El path del SDK no existe o el path es incorrecto.
- Alguna dependencia dependencia definida en tu proyecto no existe.
- Problema en algún recurso, por ejemplo en algún layout el cual no permite la construcción del proyecto.
- En ocasiones solo puede ser un problema de sincronización, puedes limping tu proyecto y construido nuevamente.